# Parse json and loop through it in php

Tags: php, arrays, json, object, foreach

I am getting following json string from `$jsonobj = json_decode($result);`

when i `print_r($jsonobj);`

I got

```
stdClass Object ( 
    [flag] => stdClass Object ( 
                    [flag] => true 
                ) 
    [records] => stdClass Object ( 
                    [news_id] => 1 
                    [news_date] => 2015-07-04 
                    [heading] => sdf 
                    [details] => sdf 
                    [dstatus] => 0 
    ) 
)
```

---

What I am trying to do is the first object comes true if records are present in database else false, now i want to loop throw `this [records]` the object in json. to print the values how to do that?\

the source I am trying to encode array

```
$sql = "select * from latest_news where dstatus=0";
$stmt = $con->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
$rows_found = $stmt->rowCount();
if($rows_found)
{
    $json_data['flag']=array('flag'=>'true');
    while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
        $json_data['records']=$row;
    }

    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    print(json_encode($json_data));
    $con->commit();

}
else
{
    $con->rollBack();
    $json_data['flag']=array('flag'=>'false');
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    print(json_encode($json_data));

}
```

Comment: Your array structure can be made more simple. Can you please post the code that is responsible for creating your ** json encoded array ** ?

Comment: if you want it as array use `json_decode($result, true)` check [Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Comment: What are you trying to loop through? There's just a single `records` object, not an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code to create the `records` element is incorrect. Each time through the loop it overwrites `$json_data['records']` instead of pushing another row onto it. To get an array of all the rows, use:

```
$json_data['records'] = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Then when you decode the JSON, you can loop through the rows:

```
foreach ($jsonobj->records as $record) {
    echo $record->news_id;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Barmar.. can you tell me is their any simplest way to encode.. or what i have done is rite..

Answer (score 0):

with `$jsonobj = json_decode($result);`

You will get

```
stdClass Object ( 
    [flag] => stdClass Object ( 
                    [flag] => true 
                ) 
    [records] => stdClass Object ( 
                    [news_id] => 1 
                    [news_date] => 2015-07-04 
                    [heading] => sdf 
                    [details] => sdf 
                    [dstatus] => 0 
    ) 
)
```

---

You can check it with

```
if($jsonobj->flag->flag == true){}
```

Try to

`print_r($jsonobj->flag->flag);`

if you want to get the record you can try with

`print_r($jsonobj->records);`

---

Because json_decode($result); will get the object result, you can also try to learn

```
var_dump(json_decode($result));
var_dump(json_decode($result, true));
```

Refer to [This Link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)